# Converting 2D array into 2D ArrayList that is backed by the original array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have looked through various examples on how to do this and I have got to this stage. My data import is copied into the array list but I am not seeing the data where I thought it would be.

When I use a 2D array it displays the imported data fine, but I want to be able to make changes to the data, hence the array list. I need the data to populate two things, first a Java Table and then I will reuse the data in an export to a spreadsheet. If you can just help me with the conversion of 2D array to a 2D (if this is what I need) `ArrayList` that would be great.

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> student_data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

System.out.println(DataImport.dataImport(file_path).length);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(DataImport.dataImport(file_path)));
for (int i = 0; i < DataImport.dataImport(file_path).length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 249; j++) {
        student_data.add(new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singleton(
                DataImport.dataImport(file_path)[i][j])));
        System.out.println(student_data.get(i, j));
    }
}
```

`DataImport.dataImport(filepath)` array displays the correct file path and data when `deepToString` is called as a check. So I know the data is there. I'm new to Java and stuck fast on this one. I modified my output to show the counters and array list when the loop completes and it now contains the data from data import, but each cell is in a separate list when what I need are rows and columns. So it is definitely the way I am populating the array list that I need help with.

Comment: `student_data.get(i,j)` Forgive me, but I cannot find method `get(int, int)` in class `java.util.ArrayList`. What am I missing?

Comment: _When I use a 2d array it displays the imported data fine, but I want to be able to make changes to the data_ Do you mean add or remove elements from the 2D array? You can do that in exactly the same way as class `java.util.ArrayList` does it. Create a new array and copy the elements from the existing array and then replace the existing array with the new one. Just have a look at the source code for class `ArrayList`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end and after understanding the method posted by Akif Hadziabdic, I developed my own solution. I have posted it below just in case anyone else is having the same issue.
Using guidance from [Multi Dimensional ArrayList in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-multi-dimensional-arraylist) I simply had to create a new arraylist within the first row iteration within the existing arraylist. So simple here is the code:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> student_data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < DataImport.dataImport(file_path).length; i++) {
    student_data.add(new ArrayList<>());
    for (int j = 0; j <= 249; j++) {
        student_data.get(i).add(DataImport.dataImport(file_path)[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `DataImport.dataImport(file_path)` is a very fast call, but you shouldn't call it repeatedly, even if it is. Only calling it once will also improve the code readability.

Since you want a 2D array converted to a 2D list, you certainly don't want to use `Collections.singleton()`. Instead, you'd want to create a list inside the outer loop.

```java
String[][] data = DataImport.dataImport(file_path);
System.out.println(data.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> student_data = new ArrayList<>();
for (String[] row : data) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String value : row) {
        list.add(value);
    }
    student_data.add(list);
}
```

The inner loop can be eliminated using the `Arrays.asList()` helper method:

```java
String[][] data = DataImport.dataImport(file_path);
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> student_data = new ArrayList<>();
for (String[] row : data)
    student_data.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(row)));
```

If you'd like to use Java 8 Streams, you'd do it like this:

```java
String[][] data = DataImport.dataImport(file_path);
List<List<String>> student_data = Arrays.stream(data)
        .map(row -> Arrays.stream(row).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods in sequence: [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-), then [`Arrays::asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) and [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableList()) to convert a multidimensional *array* to the same *list* that is backed by the original array and has a *fixed size*, since the array is always of a *fixed size*.

```java
String[][] array = {{"str1", "str2"}, {"str3"}, {"str4", "str5", "str6"}};

List<List<String>> list = Arrays
        // returns a sequential stream over the array rows
        .stream(array)
        // returns a fixed-size list backed by the
        // specified array row, disallows null
        // values when the array row is null
        .map(Arrays::asList)
        // so as not to confuse the list itself and
        // its internal lists, i.e. array rows, disallows
        // null values when the array row is null
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

// changing the data in the list
list.get(1).set(0, "str33");

// you can't add data to the inner lists and to
// the list itself, only modify existing data
// list.get(1).add("str34");
// list.add(Arrays.asList("str71"));
// UnsupportedOperationException

// output
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
System.out.println(list);
//[[str1, str2], [str33], [str4, str5, str6]]
//[[str1, str2], [str33], [str4, str5, str6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a *custom `asList`* method using the [`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method for the rows of the 2D array and then for the array itself:

```java
/**
 * Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. Changes made to
 * the array will be visible in the returned list, and changes made to the
 * list will be visible in the array...
 *
 * @param array the 2D array by which the list will be backed
 * @param <T>   the class of the objects in the 2D array
 * @return a list view of the specified array
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified array is 'null',
 *                              or one of its rows is 'null'
 * @see Arrays#asList(Object[])
 */
public static <T> List<List<T>> asList(T[][] array) {
    return Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(Arrays::asList).<List<T>>toArray(List[]::new));
}
```

```java
// test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] array = {{"A", "B"}, {"C", "D", null}};
    List<List<String>> list = asList(array);

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    // [[A, B], [C, D, null]]
    System.out.println(list);
    // [[A, B], [C, D, null]]

    list.get(1).set(2, "E");

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
    // [[A, B], [C, D, E]]
    System.out.println(list);
    // [[A, B], [C, D, E]]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

a) Do the DataImport.dataImport(file_path) only once before loops, no need to read it all the time inside the loop

```java
var rawData = DataImport.dataImport(file_path)
```

b) Second j-loop should iterate till `rawData[i].lenght`

c) Most important. You should create outer list BEFORE i-loop, inner List BEFORE j-loop. And inside j-loop add data to inner list. After j-loop - add this inner list to  outer.

Something like

```java
var rawData = DataImport.dataImport(file_path)
var studentList = new List<List<>>
for (int i = 0; i < rawData.lenght; i++) {
    var innerList = new List<>;
    for (int j = 0; i < rawData[i].lenght; j++) {
        innerList.add(rawData[i][j])
    }
    studentList.add(innerList);
}
```

Comment: 1) Many compilation errors. --- 2) Given the use of simple `for` loops, OP is likely also using an older Java version where `var` isn't supported.